# How to Limit the Amount of Rows in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, limit, rows

Similar to the limit formula in Google Sheets:

```
=query(F1:F, "select F where F contains '5' limit 10")
```

How would I limit the amount of returning rows in Google Apps Script, when I want to limit the results? Here is what I have where it pastes my return rows, and the function works correctly, but I need to limit the results to 20:

```
 ws.getRange(6, 11, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the function you are using to fetch the rows, if you need to limit the amount of returned rows then this function is necessary. Otherwise you can slice the array as Cooper point out before pasting it into your destination range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Limiting Rows**

```
var r=rows.slice(0,20);
ws.getRange(6, 11, r.length, r[0].length).setValues(r);
```

[Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: Thanks again, Cooper!